# Node.js REST API - URI Sanitizing?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, security, uri

I would like to require pages in my Node.js server based on the requested URI.

However I concern that this could be a severe security issue since user can inject some malicous chars into the url, something like `../../` and reach to my root server point and reveal all of the code.

So just like throwing a bottle of water to a big fire, I have eliminated the option to send `.` to the request.

This is not a silverbullet, probably :)

Maybe is there some standard/best practice/guide or keypoints about URI sanitizing in REST API based on Node.js?

**Edit - here the code uses the require**

```
// app.js
app.use(require('./services/router')(app));


// router.js middleware 
function router(app) {
  return function(req, res, next) {

    try {
      // checking for . in the url
      if (req.url.indexOf(".")!=-1) cast.badRequest();
      // req.url.split('/')[2] should be customers, users or anything else
      require('../../resources/' + req.url.split('/')[2] + '/' + req.url.split('/')[2] + '-router')(app);
      next();
    } catch(err) { cast.notFound(); }

  }
}

module.exports = router;

// rides-router.js (this could be users-router.js or customers-router.js)
module.exports = function(app) {

  // GET ride - select a ride
  app.get("/v1/rides/:id", dep.verifyToken(), require('./api/v1-get-ride'));

  // POST ride - insert a new ride
  app.post("/v1/rides", dep.verifyToken(), require('./api/v1-set-ride'));

  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    cast.notFound();
  });

}
```

Comment: Can you explain the actual problem - why you're trying to `require()` pages based on the URI?  We can probably come up with a better way that isn't vulnerable to URL injection.  As your question stands now, it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you've described an issue with your solution to some other problem that you have not shared.  Maybe we could help you find a bitter solution to the original problem.

Comment: I will edit my question - adding my code.

Comment: You still don't explain why you're using `require()` based on info from the URL.  That's unusual because it allows one user to run something on the server on that could affect everyone.  What is that code supposed to do and why are you running `require()` dynamically?

Comment: I have a main router in app.js - think of lobby guard in a government building. Asking you: what can I do for you?
You show him your request, then he sends the request to the devision that should handle it respectively.
If the address you specify is not found, or something went wrong, you get an error.
If the address is correct, there is a middle router handling all the requests specific only to his class.
This is named in my app as: NAME-router.js under the path: resources/NAME/NAME-router.js. There you can see all the express methods like app.get app.post app.put handled by hanlers.

Comment: This is not the normal way of doing things.  Normally, you would give your server ALL of its capabilities when it starts up and then define URLs that use each of those capabilities. There's no meaningful cost to having capabilities sitting there registered and waiting to be used so there's typically no reason to dynamically load things.  I still don't know why you're trying to dynamically load code based on some URL you didn't previously know about.

Comment: app.get, or literally app, is need to be accessed in the rides router page, right?
I should bring it first from the app.js file to the required page. So I read the URI and extract just the resource name of the first argument in the slashes, that could be rides, users, clients, products etc..

What is the problem with this? (As long I sanitize the user inputs, like, checking for the URI length, checking if there malicious chars and so for and so on).

Comment: Well, there's no reason to do it that way.  You can just predefine routes for each type of resource.  Put the approved resources in a list and initialize their routes at startup with a loop if you want.  Plus using `require()` at the run-time of a server is bad.   It uses synchronous I/O which should never be used at request time.  This whole thing could also easily be driven from a Javascript table of data.  There's no need to use your file system as the table.

Comment: Though I'm recommending against the `require()` based on something you parsed from the URL, you could create a table of pre-approved things to run and only run it if it's in that table.  That would be safe.

Comment: White labeling is good way for handling bad things.
Actually I am dong like so, just to avoid this list (that could be long):
app.use(require('../../resources/rides/rides-router'));
app.use(require('../../resources/products/products-router')); and turn into one like  this:
require('../../resources/' + req.url.split('/')[2] + '/' + req.url.split('/')[2] + '-router')(app);

Comment: I posted an answer with my recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked how to do it safer.  My recommendation is that you put all the resources in an array and run all the `app.use()` statements with one loop that pulls the resource names from the array at server startup.

I don't like running synchronous `require()` during a request and I don't like loading code based on user specified characters.  Both are avoided with my recommendation.

```
// add routes for all resources
const resourceList = ['rides', 'products', ...];

for (let r of resourceList) {
    app.use(`/${r}`, require(`./resources/${r}/${r}-router`));
}
```

This seems like less code and 100% safe and no running of synchronous `require()` during a request.

**Advantages:**

1. Fully whitelisted.
2. No user input involved in selecting code to run.
3. No synchronous `require()` during request processing.
4. All routes installed at server initialization time.
5. Any errors in route loading (like a missing route file) occur at server startup, not during a user request.